# Firestore custom Document ID with setting data does not work - CollectionReference

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

In my firestore cloud I want to store my user data. So the document ID should be the user ID from auth. When I set the document ID manually I can't set up data.
That's my code:

```
currentuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

CollectionReference mFirestoreProfiles = mFirestore.collection("profiles").document(currentuser).set();

     Profile profile = new Profile(
          email,
          birth
     );

mFirestoreProfiles.add(profile)
     .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
               Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
               .make((getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView()), "Registration successful.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
               snackbar.show();
               }
          })
      .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
          @Override
          public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
               Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
               .make((getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView()), e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
               snackbar.show();
               }
          });
```

I always get an error with "CollectionReference" in this line:

```
mFirestore.collection("profiles").document(currentuser).set();
```

It would be very nice if someone would take the time to help me with this (truly stupid) problem.

Regards
Jere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line of code:

```
CollectionReference mFirestoreProfiles = mFirestore.collection("profiles").document(currentuser).set();
```

Will always produce an exception. To solve this, please change the above line of code to:

```
DocumentReference mFirestoreProfiles = mFirestore.collection("profiles").document(currentuser);
Profile profile = new Profile(email, birth);
mFirestoreProfiles.set(profile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Document written successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Even if you were passing to the `set()` method the `profile` object, an exception will also be thrown because `set()` method return type is a `Task` and not a `CollectionReference`.

Comment: Thank your for your answer but this does not work...
The first line of code causes this error: Incompatible types.
Required:
com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference
Found:
com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference

Comment: My bad, sorry! Just copied and paste it. Should be `set()` instead of `add()`. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: The problem is that this line of code: CollectionReference mFirestoreProfiles = mFirestore.collection("profiles").document(currentuser); causes this error. Incompatible types. Required: com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference Found: com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference

Comment: So now I get another error :-(... addOnSuccessListener
(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener<? super java.lang.Void>)
in Task cannot be applied
to
(anonymous com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener<com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference>) in this line: mFirestoreProfiles.set(profile).addOnSuccessListener...

Comment: You are using the exact code `.addOnSuccessListener(/* ... */);`?

Comment: .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>()

Comment: Please see again my updated answer. Does it work this way?